# Webpack ExtractTextPlugin without babel

Tags: css, webpack

I'm trying to get webpack to bundle all my stylesheets but I'm at a loss.
I don't want to use babel, so I try to do this in my main.js file:
require('./styles/core.css');

When I run webpack i get the following error:

`You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

My loader is:

```
loaders: [
  {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!scss'),
      include: __dirname + '/app/styles'
    }
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have loader only for `.scss` and you are trying to use it on `.css` file. Change test in loader to:

```
test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
```